# Customization Facebook OpenGraph Title

Tags: plugin-seomatic

I am using SEOmatic on Craft 2 and want to give the user the ability to customize the Title field of Facebook's OpenGraph Title. For example, instead of showing just the Title, add a "How To" before the title is displayed. [image: Article title only]

vs. [image]

Is there a way to do this without using a custom field and have the "How To" only display only on when the article is shared on Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [this page](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/10.-Dynamic-Twig-SEO-Meta), you can try this:

```
{% set og = seomaticMeta.og %}
{% set og = og | merge({'title': 'How to: ' ~ seomaticMeta.og.title}) %}
{% set seomaticMeta = seomaticMeta | merge({'og': og}) %}
```

Comment: I checked this out but my concern is that it would add "how-to" to all of the open graphs for the entries site. I don't want the og for other parts of the website to saw "How To'. Is there a way to test something like : if entry equals article then set og this way, if not set it another way? Or is that crazy talk.

Comment: You have 2 options: 
1. You can create special template for How-To articles and add this code only into this template
2. You can add a How-to lightswitch field in the control panel, then check in the template if it is true and add the code above.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I'll let you know once I've implemented it.